# Unable to build android bundle or ios etc

Tags: flutter

```
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/enough_platform_widgets-0.7.4/lib/src/platform/decorated_platform_textfield.dart:536:20: Error: The argument type 'bool?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'bool' because 'bool?' is nullable and 'bool' isn't.
          enabled: enabled,
                   ^
../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_platform_widgets-3.3.5/lib/src/platform_text_field.dart:578:30: Error: The argument type 'bool?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'bool' because 'bool?' is nullable and 'bool' isn't.
      enabled: data?.enabled ?? enabled,
                             ^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/src/main/groovy/flutter.groovy' line: 1350

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command '/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

After upgrade flutter 3.16, expected it to build the executable file for Android or iOS but its keep giving the error.

Comment: seems like problem of enough_platform_widgets package.

Comment: It would be good if you can post the code snipped

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a bug with `DecoratedPlatformTextField` inside the `enough_platform_widgets` package.
It has been fixed in [this PR](https://github.com/Enough-Software/enough_platform_widgets/pull/19) on 11/18/2023, so it will probably be available in the next release after v0.7.4.

If needed, you could take the fixed version from [the GitHub repository](https://github.com/Enough-Software/enough_platform_widgets) and work with that until the fix is officially released.

---

Update: The fix has been released in [v1.0.0](https://github.com/Enough-Software/enough_platform_widgets/releases)

Answer (score 1):

If you facing a problem by replacing the 1.0.0 version of enough_platform_widgets then just go to the file  as per @jraufeisen

> C:\Users<myuser>\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.flutter-io.cn\enough_platform_widgets-0.7.3\lib\src\platform\decorated_platform_textfield.dart

then find and replace below two lines

```
final bool? enabled;
```

by

```
final bool enabled;
```

and

```
this.enabled,
```

by

```
this.enabled = true,
```